# React Native - How to switch between several images depending on 2 states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, state

I am coding an alarm application right now and I can't seem to figure out how to display the desired image.
There are two states:

1. switchValue : the alarm is enabled(off) or disabled
2. alarmValue : the alarm is on or off (triggered or not)

Right now only switchValue is displayed and it works depending on true/false. But how can I switch between images depending on switchValue AND alarmValue AND undefined if the alarm is not connected?

I get 'switchValue' and 'alarmValue' through redux toolkit.

Here's my code:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { toggleOn, toggleOff } from '../components/switch';
import { alarmOn, alarmOff} from '../components/alarm';

function Home({navigation}) {

   const imageAlarmOff = require('../images/Alarm_off.png'); // enabled but not triggered
   const imageAlarmOn = require('../images/Alarm_on.png');  // enabled and triggered
   const imageAlarmDisabled = require('../images/Alarm_off_disabled.png');  // disabled
   const imageAlarmUndefined = require('../images/Alarm_undefined.png');  // not connected

   const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.switch.active);
   const alarmValue = useSelector((state) => state.alarm.active);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();


   return (
      <View style={globalStyles.containerBodyHome}>

        <View style={globalStyles.containerMainHome}>
          <ImageBackground 
            style={globalStyles.imageHome} 
            source={switchValue ? imageAlarmOff : imageAlarmDisabled}
          >
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>

      </View>
   );
}


export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like to manage multiple images?

You can use switch statement and base on switchValue return appropriate image.

```
function Home({navigation}) {

   const imageAlarmOff = require('../images/Alarm_off.png'); // enabled but not triggered
   const imageAlarmOn = require('../images/Alarm_on.png');  // enabled and triggered
   const imageAlarmDisabled = require('../images/Alarm_off_disabled.png');  // disabled
   const imageAlarmUndefined = require('../images/Alarm_undefined.png');  // not connected

   const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.switch.active);
   const alarmValue = useSelector((state) => state.alarm.active);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   const handleImage = () => {
    switch(switchValue) {
      case true: {
        if(alarmValue) return imageAlarmOn
        return imageAlarmOff
      }
      case false: {
       return imageAlarmDisabled
      }
     default: {
      return imageAlarmUndefined
     }}}


   return (
      <View style={globalStyles.containerBodyHome}>

        <View style={globalStyles.containerMainHome}>
          <ImageBackground 
            style={globalStyles.imageHome} 
            source={handleImage()}
          >
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>

      </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: Yes, you understood that correctly. Thank you very much, your suggestion definitely looks like it will give me the desired outcome. Unfortunately it's not working properly, the default image is displayed and I failed to fix it. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the switch value? Please change it to true, false instead of 'ACTIVE', 'NOT_ACTIVE'. That was an example, but I see that you have there booleans. Edited the answer. Please take a look.

Comment: I tried a few things and in the end it worked with only if-statements, but thank you very much for your help, I'm going to try it out again with your solution.